# How can set not null in migration table laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I set user table as below

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->unsigned()-> nullable(false) -> change()->default(1);
        $table->string('confirmation_code')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('confirmed')->unsigned()->nullable(false) -> change()->default(1);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->unsignedInteger('deleted_at');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

but show error as below

```
     Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: alter table `` add `status` tinyint unsigned not null default '1' after `password`, add `confirmation_code` varchar(255) null after `status`, add `confirmed` tinyint(1) not null default '1' after `confirmation_code`, add `deleted_at` timestamp null)

   at C:\xampp\htdocs\cron\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
663|         catch (Exception $e) {
 > 664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''")
  C:\xampp\htdocs\cron\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452

  2   PDO::prepare("alter table `` add `status` tinyint unsigned not null default '1' after `password`, add `confirmation_code` varchar(255) null after `status`, add `confirmed` tinyint(1) not null default '1' after `confirmation_code`, add `deleted_at` timestamp null")
  C:\xampp\htdocs\cron\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
```

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

please help me to correct this migration.
I think I wrong in not null

Comment: What does `->change()` do? Haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the `->change()` method in `Schema::create()`, as it will try to change a column that hasn't been created yet. To create a column that allows null values, simply do:

```
Schema::create("table", function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string("column"); // Omit ->nullable() to force `NOT NULL`
  $table->string("nullable_column")->nullable();
});
```

When this migration is run, and the table is created, `table.column` will be initialized with `NOT NULL`, and `table.nullable_column` will be initialized as `NULL`.

Now, if you need to change these **in a later migration**, that is when you use `->nullable(false)->change();`, like so:

```
Schema::table("table", function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string("column")->nullable()->change();
  $table->string("nullable_column")->nullable(false)->change();
});
```

Following this migration, `table.column` will allow `NULL`, while `table.nullable_column` will not.

Comment: So to use omit -> nullable()?

Comment: *"// Omit ->nullable() to force `NOT NULL`"* That's what I said :P As long as you don't use `->nullable()` in `Schema::create()`, the column will default to `NOT NULL`